# Should supportFragmentManager replace resources?

Tags: android

I'm using the newest version of Android studio to experiment with writing Kotlin. I created an activity for displaying an icon, and the IDE automatically added this to onCreate:

```
class ExamplesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_examples)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.profileRight, ExamplesFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
}
```

When I started up the vm, I got the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup,
which I traced to the line .replace(R.id.profileRight...

(profileRight is the id I assigned to the icon I added to the fragment's xml file. )

When I remove the line starting with .replace, it all works fine! So my question is, what did the IDE add here and why? Am I losing some functionality by removing this line? And is this an error in Android Studio's auto completion?

Addition:
Thanks laalto, I think this might be what you are talking about. The IDE also added this to the fragment file:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    }
```

Maybe the container: ViewGroup? is what is actually causing the issue.

Comment: There's an activity that adds a fragment to a container with id `profileRight`. Likely that id points to an `ImageView` and not a `ViewGroup` (any layout class really) that could be a container for fragments. `activity_examples` ought to have some container layout for a the fragment.

Comment: "it all works fine" -- how are you defining "works fine"? Without that `replace()` call, the `FragmentTransaction` that you are trying to `commitNow()` does not do anything.

Comment: The id is pointing to an ImageView, yes, but this error happens even if activity_examples does not reference it. By 'it all works fine' I mean that the error does not crash the app. The fragment is loaded without issue.

Comment: I think .replace(R.id... must be trying to replace the ImageView with a ViewGroup, but why?